# array_merge two like arrays: unsetting right hand side causes left hand side to not show up

Tags: php, arrays, runtime-error, unset, array-merge

Lets say I have two arrays:

```
$a = array(
    'product' => array(
        'name' => "Some Product Name",
        'description' => 'Some Product Description',
        'productLink' => 'some.uri.url'
    )
);

$b = array(
    'product' => array(
        'name' => 'Some Product Name',
        'description' => 'Some other Description',
        'price' => 10.95,
        'tax' => 0.08,
    )
);
```

I'm wanting to combine these two arrays but wanting to keep side $a intact regarding name and description. I assume:

```
unset($b['product']['name']);
unset($b['product']['description']);
$c = array_merge($a, $b);
```

should result in:

```
$c = array(
    'product' => array(
        'name' => "Some Product Name",
        'description' => 'Some Product Description',
        'productLink' => 'some.uri.url',
        'price' => 10.95,
        'tax' => 0.08,
    )
);
```

buuuut I see this:

```
$c = array (
    'product' => array (
        'price' => 10.95,
        'tax' => 0.08,
    ),
);
```

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$a = array(
    'product' => array(
        'name' => "Some Product Name",
        'description' => 'Some Product Description',
        'productLink' => 'some.uri.url'
    )
);

$b = array(
    'product' => array(
        'name' => 'Some Product Name',
       'description' => 'Some other Description',
        'price' => 10.95,
        'tax' => 0.08,
    )
);

unset($b['product']['name']);
unset($b['product']['description']);
$c = array_merge($a['product'], $b['product']);

print_r($c);
```

I think when you merge it overrides on the first level... So 'product' from $b is overriding 'product' from $a.

Answer (score 0):

Analyze carefully and you'll realize you want to merge the `product` key of both arrays and not the arrays themselves, so this should work (Notice I swapped `$b` first and `$a` second so the values of `$a` take precedence):

```
$c['product'] = array_merge($b['product'],$a['product']); 
print_r($c);
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [product] => Array
        (
            [name] => Some Product Name
            [description] => Some Product Description
            [productLink] => some.uri.url
            [price] => 10.95
            [tax] => 0.08
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

@koala_dev, you are correct, I was wanting to merge those keys, but this was a tiny subset of the arrays and nested arrays of the much larger dataset I have to replace.  In my research and testing (now that I have gotten sleep), **array_merge** will only merge the first level of arrays from the left to the right with the arrays replacing into the first overwriting but not recursively overwriting.

**array_merge_recursive** did not work either, because if it found two keys similar, it would create another array with those keys, when the structure of the array is critical.

**array_replace_recursive** Does indeed do what I was wanting with one caveat: if arrays are numeric keyed the values of the second array will replace the left hand array's numeric keys:

```
$ab = array('one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3);
$cd = array(1, 2, 3);
$ef = array('one' => 10, 'two' => 3, 'four' => 40);
$zz = array_replace_recursive($ab, $cd, $ef);
```

will result in:

```
array (
    'one' => 10,
    'two' => 3,
    'three' => 3,
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
    'four' => 40,
)
```